# What are some interesting implications of this similarity?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

I noticed that there is some similarity between [*the Baire property*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_of_Baire) and the property of measurable:

- We say that a set $X$ has the Baire property if there is an open set $U$ such that $U\Delta X$ is meager. The collection of all sets with the Baire property turns out to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all of the open sets and the meager sets.
- In fact, we can define the collection of Lebesgue measurable sets to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets and the nullsets.

My questions:

1. I wonder if there are some interesting results from this observation.
2. Is there a general rule to form a useful notion by forming the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all of the open (or closed) sets and the $\sigma$-ideal (or other *small* sets)?
3. The notion of *measurable* is induced by some value function, i.e., the outer measure. Is there a value function that can induce the notion of the Baire property?

Comment: A good text ( infact best text) Measure and Category: A Survey of the Analogies Between Topological and Measure Spaces
 by John C. Oxtoby

Comment: Another one: **REAL ANALYSIS
 $\text{bruckner}^2$ ,thomson**.